# Equalize batteries

Tags: batteries, parallel, battery-operated, discharge

I have two (2) 12V, 7Ah SLA batteries. I want to use them in parallel to support my load. I am not sure about their charge state. How do I equalize them to same voltage and current so that my connected circuits (battery charger cut off, low battery cutoff and battery level indicator ) works fine.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?

Answer (score 3):

Equalise them by connecting a resistor between them, perhaps an automotive filament bulb. Once their voltages are the same, connect them directly in parallel. Use and charge them in parallel.

Comment: Should I connect the bulb with positive wire of one battery and negative of other battery and connect remaining negative and positive terminals of both batteries to eachother directly?

Comment: If you need to ask that question, then you need to do a lot more research before you mess with batteries. The safest thing for you to do is to just leave the batteries alone. But I'll answer the question, as it may be safer for you than not. You're eventually going to connect the two batteries in parallel, so connect their negative terminals to each other. Instead of connecting their positive terminals directly together, which could cause excessive current flow if their SOC's differ, connect the positives with a resistor. When the voltage on has dropped to zero, replace it with a wire.

Answer (score 1):

You can coarsely determine their state of charge by measuring their *quiescent* voltage -- i.e. their voltage when you *haven't* tried charging or discharging them in the last few hours.

Lead-acid batteries (and, well, a lot of batteries) become less *charge-efficient* as they get nearer to top-of-charge. As such, if they are reasonably near, they will *tend to* self-balance.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a bit of leeway - if you measure the quiescent voltages and then start to charge the lower-voltage battery, as soon as it reaches the voltage of the higher voltage battery *while charging* (this will probably happen immediately) you know that you can connect them directly together without any more current flowing between them than the normal charging current.  I’d then do a float charge at moderate current to ensure that they are equalised.